# MassTransit: Configure queue for multiple API instances

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, queue, publish-subscribe, masstransit

I'm introducing myself into Event-driven architecture using **MassTransit** with **RabbitMQ** on localhost and **AWS** on live environments, using **.NET 5 Web APIs**.

I have an API (**#API-1**) which produces events, such as **EntityCreated**, **EntityUpdated**, **EntityDeleted**, etc.

Then I have another API (**#API-2**) which stores an in-memory copy of entities. This **#API-2** must subscribe to those events in order to update its local cache.
The **#API-2** will have multiple running instances, let's say 3.

- How should I configure **#API-2** so that **all of the instances receive the same message**?

**Producer Configuration (#API-1):**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq();
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

**Consumer Configuration (#API-2):**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EntityCreatedConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<EntityUpdatedConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<EntityDeletedConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different endpoint names. Each endpoint gets its own queue and binding, so if you use the same endpoint name, you get one queue and all instances started to compete for messages.

It is a common mistake, that's why it's even [mentioned](https://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html#sharing-a-queue) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I assume I should suffix the queue name with some unique identifier, such as the MachineName. Is this a good practice?
Moreover, I believe I should mark those Queues as AutoDelete so that they are removed if an instance is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

To properly configure instance-specific endpoints for your consumers, you can use the `Endpoint` configuration when adding the consumer. I've updated your code to show how to use it.

```
string instanceId = "SomeUniqueValue";

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EntityCreatedConsumer>()        
        .Endpoint(e => e.InstanceId = instanceId);
    x.AddConsumer<EntityUpdatedConsumer>()
        .Endpoint(e => e.InstanceId = instanceId);
    x.AddConsumer<EntityDeletedConsumer>()
        .Endpoint(e => e.InstanceId = instanceId);

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

The instanceId can be pulled from the environment, or even random. If you want the queues to be removed when the process exits, you can specify:

```
.Endpoint(e =>
{
    e.InstanceId = instanceId;
    e.Temporary = true;
});
```

> This was added in [v7.0.4](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#general)